# Using combn to make specific functions for grouped pair-wise, row-wise comparisons

Tags: r, combinations, combn

This is a small section of a dataset I'm working on.

```
dat2 <- read.table(text = "
   nodepair  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 ES   
 1 A1_A1        0    21     0     0     0     0     0     0    78 45   
 2 A2_A1        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    99 45   
 3 A2_A2        0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0    98 45   
 4 A3_A1        0     0     0     0     0     6     1     3    89 45   
 5 A3_A2        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    99 45   
 6 A1_A1        0    20     0     0     0     0     0     0    65 46   
 7 A2_A1        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    85 46   
 8 A2_A2        0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0    84 46   
 9 A3_A1        0     0     0     0     2     6     3     3    71 46   
 10 A3_A2        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    85 46   
 11 A1_A1        0    25     0     0     0     0     0     0    45 47   
 12 A2_A1        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    70 47   
 13 A2_A2        0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0    69 47   
 14 A3_A1        0     0     0     0     0     8     0     1    61 47   
 15 A3_A2        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    70 47   
 16 A1_A1        0    37     0     0     0     0     0     0    77 48   
 17 A2_A1        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   114 48   
 18 A2_A2        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   114 48   
 19 A3_A1        0     0     0     0     2     9     0     3   100 48   
 20 A3_A2        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   114 48   
 ", header = TRUE)
```

I'm trying to write a program that will do all pairwise comparisons (grouped by the nodepair) across the 'ES' groups.

I'd like to write a series of functions to specifically compare each pair of rows.  For example, when V1:V9 is > 0 for both ESs, this should result in 1, indicating presence of data.

I'm imagining the output to look something like this:

```
 dat3 <- read.table(text = "
    nodepair1 nodepair2  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9    
    A1_A1(45) A1_A1(46)   0     0    1     0     0     0     0     0     1        
  ", header = TRUE)
```

etc.

Unfortunately, I haven't gotten very far:

```
 dat2 <- dat2 %>%
   group_by(nodepair) %>%
   col2 = t(combn(nodepair,2)))
```

I'm pretty sure I need 'combn' here, but I'm very new to this function and can't figure it out.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. Are you looking for every row with the same nodepair but with a different ES to be compared?

Comment: I‘m also not sure what‘s the expected output, so please provide an output example that shows a bit more what you mean with „all rowwise comparisons“.

Comment: Your data has 4 ES groups, but in your text and output you only refer to ES 45 and 46. can you please clarify if only these two ES groups should be considered or all?

Comment: Yes, I need to consider all pairwise combinations: so 45 and 46, 45 and 47, 45, and 48, 46 and 47, 46 and 48 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now with the TO having clarified their question, I'd propose the following solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

ES_combs <- combn(unique(dat2$ES), 2, simplify = FALSE)

dat2 |> 
  group_split(nodepair) |> 
  map(.x = _,
      .f = \(df) df |> 
        map(.x = 1:length(ES_combs),
            .f = ~df |> 
               filter(ES %in% ES_combs[[.x]]) |> 
               summarize(nodepair = first(nodepair),
                         ES_1 = ES[1],
                         ES_2 = ES[2],
                         across(V1:V9, ~as.numeric(all(. >0)))))) |> 
  bind_rows()
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 30 × 12
   nodepair  ES_1  ES_2    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9
   <chr>    <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A1_A1       45    46     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 2 A1_A1       45    47     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 3 A1_A1       45    48     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 4 A1_A1       46    47     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 5 A1_A1       46    48     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 6 A1_A1       47    48     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 7 A2_A1       45    46     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 8 A2_A1       45    47     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 9 A2_A1       45    48     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
10 A2_A1       46    47     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
11 A2_A1       46    48     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
12 A2_A1       47    48     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
13 A2_A2       45    46     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
14 A2_A2       45    47     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
15 A2_A2       45    48     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
16 A2_A2       46    47     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
17 A2_A2       46    48     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
18 A2_A2       47    48     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
19 A3_A1       45    46     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
20 A3_A1       45    47     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     1
21 A3_A1       45    48     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     1
22 A3_A1       46    47     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     1
23 A3_A1       46    48     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     1
24 A3_A1       47    48     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     1
25 A3_A2       45    46     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
26 A3_A2       45    47     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
27 A3_A2       45    48     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
28 A3_A2       46    47     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
29 A3_A2       46    48     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
30 A3_A2       47    48     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

This probably needs a bit of explanation:

- We start with creating all pairwise combinations of ES in your data frame and assign it to a list object `ES_combs`
- We then take your data and split it by nodepair group into a list, where each list object is the data for one nodepair group.
- We then initiate the outer `map` where we go through each group's data frame. It is important here to define an anonymous function, because we have an inner `map`, so we can't use the .x parameter twice.
- The inner `map` takes each combination pair from `ES_combs` and filters the current group's data to these two rows. We then apply the summarize part.
- As a last step, we use `bind_rows` to merge everything into a nice tibble instead of having an annoyingly long list.

Comment: tried this and it works for me but, why isn't V7 returning "1" at A3_A1, as they are both > 0 in the dataset?

Comment: yep this will do it and looks good. One last thing, I can't upgrade to R 4.1 (older computer) so I'm trying to do this with the older piping (%>%). Most lines look good except `map(.x = _ .f = \(df) df %>%` which doesn't recognize the `_` and the `\(df)`

Comment: Replace the underscore by a dot. This should hopefully do the trick. Or you could delete the whole .x = _ line.

Comment: the `.x = .` worked, but now R is saying "unexpected token '\', expected ',' after expression". re: the `.f = \(df) df` I also tried deleting the whole .x=_ line too.  Is there another way of writing the `.f = \(df)df` bit?

Comment: Instead of \\(df) write function(df).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

```
library(tidyverse)

# create a function which compares one combination of rows with each other
comparer <- function(comb) {
  bind_cols(
    nodepair1 = paste0(dat2[comb[1], 1], "(", dat2[comb[1], 11], ")"),
    nodepair2 = paste0(dat2[comb[2], 1], "(", dat2[comb[2], 11], ")"),
    dat2[comb[1], 2:10] > 0 & dat2[comb[2], 2:10] > 0
  )
}

combs <- combn(1:nrow(dat2), 2, simplify = FALSE)

# then apply that to each combination of rows for the dataset
map_df(combs, comparer)

# Output:
# A tibble: 190 × 11
   nodepair1 nodepair2 V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   
   <chr>     <chr>     <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
 1 A1_A1(45) A2_A1(45) FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
 2 A1_A1(45) A2_A2(45) FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
 3 A1_A1(45) A3_A1(45) FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
 4 A1_A1(45) A3_A2(45) FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
 5 A1_A1(45) A1_A1(46) FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
 6 A1_A1(45) A2_A1(46) FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
 7 A1_A1(45) A2_A2(46) FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
 8 A1_A1(45) A3_A1(46) FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
 9 A1_A1(45) A3_A2(46) FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
10 A1_A1(45) A1_A1(47) FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
# ℹ 180 more rows
```

Update: If you only want to compare ones with the same 'nodepair' value, you can do this:

```
processor <- function(x) {
  map_df(combn(x, 2, simplify = FALSE), comparer)
}

dat2 |>
  mutate(n = row_number()) |>
  summarise(comparisons = map(list(n), processor), .by = nodepair) |>
  unnest(comparisons)

# Output:
# A tibble: 30 × 12
   nodepair nodepair1 nodepair2 V1    V2    V3    V4    V5   
   <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
 1 A1_A1    A1_A1(45) A1_A1(46) FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 2 A1_A1    A1_A1(45) A1_A1(47) FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 3 A1_A1    A1_A1(45) A1_A1(48) FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 4 A1_A1    A1_A1(46) A1_A1(47) FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 5 A1_A1    A1_A1(46) A1_A1(48) FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 6 A1_A1    A1_A1(47) A1_A1(48) FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 7 A2_A1    A2_A1(45) A2_A1(46) FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 8 A2_A1    A2_A1(45) A2_A1(47) FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 9 A2_A1    A2_A1(45) A2_A1(48) FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
10 A2_A1    A2_A1(46) A2_A1(47) FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# ℹ 20 more rows
```

Note: in all of these, it's using TRUE and FALSE. TRUE and FALSE are equivalent to 1 and 0 - indeed, you can see by doing TRUE + TRUE, which equals 2. I could wrap the `dat2[comb[1], 2:10] > 0 & dat2[comb[2], 2:10] > 0` in `as.integer`, but I figured you would understand.

Comment: I also tried this method and it works for a small df, but when I apply it to a large df, it gets quite hung up at   `map_df(combs, comparer)`

Comment: @ChristopherCourse you don't want that one, you want the update 